# Why does Pythons' set() return a set item instead of a list

Tags: python

I quite often use `set()` to remove duplicates from lists. After doing so, I always directly change it back to a list.

```
a = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5] 
b = list(set(a))
```

Why does `set()` return a `set` item, instead of simply a list?

```
type(set(a)) == set # is true
```

Is there a use for `set` items that I have failed to understand?

Comment: sorry why do you think that calling the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) constructor should return anything other than a `set`?

Comment: `set` is a type, not a method of `list`.

Comment: @EdChum I guess my question is more general. What use is a `set` besides filtering out doubles from a `list`?

Comment: People don't always want a list. Sometimes people actually want a set, and that's why they called `set`. Sets are really fast for testing containment.

Comment: it's an unordered container, it's useful in that it maintains uniqueness, so no duplicates, plus it offers fast lookup via hashing, you should check the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html for other use cases

Comment: Many. Cumputing intersection between sets, difference, union... check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for a better understanding of the use of `sets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, by doubles you mean duplicate? and set() will always return a set because it is a data structure in python like lists. when you are calling set you are creating an object of set(). 
rest of the information about sets you can find here
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `set`s have many uses. They have lots of nice operations documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) which lists don't have. One very useful difference is that membership testing (`x in a`) can be much faster than for a list.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, I won't go into why `set` does not return a `list` but like you stated:

*I quite often use set() to remove doubles from lists. After doing so, I always **directly change it back to a list**.*

You could use `OrderedDict` if you really **hate going back** to changing it to a list:

```
source_list = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5]
from collections import OrderedDict
print(OrderedDict((x, True) for x in source_list).keys())
```

OUTPUT:

```
odict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, for certain operations if you use `set` instead of `list`, it is faster. Python wiki has query [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) in which speed of operations of various data types are given. Note that if you have few elements in your list or set, you will most probably do not notice difference, but with more elements it become more important.
Notice that for example if you want to make in-place removal, for `list` it is `O(n)` meaning that for 10 times longer list it will need 10 times more time, while for `set` and `s.difference_update(t)` where `s` is set, `t` is set with one element to be removed from `s`, time is `O(1)` i.e. independent from number of elements of `s`.